# What's the difference between Ethereum blockchain and Ethereum Classic blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-classic

One project specifically was born after a hard-fork (Ethereum Classic) and the other one still having value but, what differences can we find between these two project concerning the blockchain?

Comment: i invite you to read this document : https://ethereumclassic.github.io/assets/Ethereum_Classic_-_The_New_Original_Innovator.pdf

Comment: @BadrBellaj please don't link opinion/advertising type content.  The approach of the duplicated question (simply identifying clear technical differences) is the appropriate on-topic mode for a stack exchange site.

Comment: @JeffColeman in my opinion the document is not an ad, they present what they are planing different from ETH in the technical level . check slides 20 -25.

Comment: I agree there is technical content in there, but it's not exactly wikipedia-style neutral point of view.  In those situations I would usually extract the relevant content and then link back to the document as a source so that random passers-by don't have to sort through and figure out what is opinion and what is fact (since being linked from stack exchange without specific content being extracted is effectively an endorsement).

Answer (score 1):

Technically the two are almost identical. Ethereum Classic is Ethereum but without the one-off state change that reallocated funds held by the DAO attacker's contract to contracts where they could be returned to their original owners.

The main difference is in the social layer: Ethereum Classic implicitly has a social contract based on the principle that code is law and the rules should not be changed.

In future it seems likely that they will diverge technically; For example, if and when Ethereum moves to proof-of-stake, Ethereum Classic may decline to adopt this change and stick with proof-of-work. Relatedly, Ethereum Classic has already made a change to remove the "difficulty bomb" which Ethereum developers originally introduced to force the network to accept an upgrade, which was intended to facilitate the transition to proof-of-stake.